# Difficulty with Proof of Integrability

Tags: integration, proof-explanation

I'm working on a proof on integrability, and cannot seem to grasp the final step.

The theorem is that: if we have two integrable functions, $f$ and $g$, over the interval $[a,b]$, then we can say their sum, $f + g$, is also integrable and equal to the sum of their integrals. I can prove everything but the final step: that $\int_a^b (f + g) = \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g$.

I understand, I believe, everything up until the point that we conclude $U(f+g, P) - L(f+g, P) < \epsilon$, and thus $f+g$ is integrable. From here, there seems to be a jump into concluding that, thus the integral of $f + g$ is equal to the sum of the integral of $f$ and $g$, and seems to have something to do with the definition of integrability, i.e., since it is integrable, we can conclude that $\int (f+g) = U(f+g) = L(f+g)$, and we had already that $\int f = L(f) = U(f)$ and $\int g = L(g) = L(f)$, but I can't figure out how to string these facts together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it would help, I could give--with citation to Ross's analysis text--his argument for why this is so. It may help if I could lay out the exact argument I don't understand.

Comment: Isn't $U(f+g,P)\le U(f,P)+U(g,P)$ and $L(f+g,P)\ge L(f,P)+L(g,P)$, so $U(f+g)\le U(f)+U(g)$ and $L(f+g)\ge L(f)+L(g)$? Does that help?

Comment: Checking my notes, I agree on all of those. (It would take me a while to re-derive them as I'm quite new to this, though I was able to when I initially wrote the proof.) From here, though, I'm still not able to piece together the rest.

Comment: But $f$ and $g$ are integrable, i.e. $\int_a^b f=U(f)=L(f)$ and similar for $g$... so just replace that in the previous inequalities...

Comment: That helps a lot. Ok, let's see if I got this. So, because $f$ is integrable, $\int_a^b f = U(f) = L(f)$ and since $g$ is integrable, $\int_a^b g = U(g) = L(g)$. So $U(f + g) \leq U(f) + U(g)$ implies that $U(f+g) \leq \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g$ and $L(f+g) \geq L(f) + L(g)$ implies that $L(f+g) \geq \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g$. Then, since $(f+g)$ is integrable by the rest of this proof, $U(f+g) = L(f+g) = \int_a^b (f+g)$, and we have that $\int_a^b (f+g) \geq \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g$ and $\int_a^b (f+g) \leq \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g$, which necessitates equality. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, the more I work with this, I can't quite get $U(f+g) \leq U(f) + U(g)$. I know $U(f+g) \leq U(f+g, P)$ and $L(f+g) \leq L(f+g, P)$, and the same is true for each of $f$ and $g$, but how do we get that the lower and upper integrals of the sum, $f+g$, is less than or equal to the sum of the individual lower and upper sums?

Comment: I understand, see also @RRL's answer that came in the meantime. $L(f+g,P)\ge L(f,P)+L(g,P)$ is clear, but $L(f+g)\ge L(f)+L(g)$ doesn't follow directly from it. Still, for any $\epsilon\gt 0$ there is a partition $P_1$ such that $L(f,P_1)\gt L(f)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and a partition $P_2$ such that $L(g,P_2)\gt L(g)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Taking common refinement $P$ of $P_1,P_2$ you have $L(f+g)\ge L(f+g,P)\ge L(f,P)+L(g,P)\gt L(f)+L(g)-\epsilon$. As this is valid for every $\epsilon\gt 0$, you get $L(f,g)\ge L(f)+L(g)$... and similar for upper sums.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion, let's use the standard notation and definitions for lower and upper sums and integrals:

$$\overline{\int}_a^b f = \inf_P U(P,f), \quad\underline{\int}_a^b f = \sup_P L(P,f). $$

If we can show

$$\tag{1}\underline{\int}_a^b f + \underline{\int}_a^b g \leqslant \underline{\int}_a^b (f+g) \leqslant \overline{\int}_a^b (f+g) \leqslant \overline{\int}_a^b f + \overline{\int}_a^b g, $$

we are finished, since if $f$ and $g$ are integrable both the LHS and RHS equal $\int_a^b f + \int_a^bg$.  This forces equality between the lower and upper integrals of $f+g$, proving both integrability of $f+g$ and $\int_a^b(f+g) = \int_a^b f + \int_b g.$

I will show how to prove the inequality on the LHS of (1) by contradiction. The proof of the RHS inequality is similar.

If we assume

$$\underline{\int}_a^b (f+g)  <  \underline{\int}_a^b f  +  \underline{\int}_a^b g ,$$
then it follows that 
$$\underline{\int}_a^b (f+g)  -  \underline{\int}_a^b g  <  \underline{\int}_a^b f,$$
and there exists a partition $P$ such that
$$\underline{\int}_a^b (f+g)  -   \underline{\int}_a^b g  <  L(P,f)  \leqslant \underline{\int}_a^b f.$$

Rearranging we get

$$\underline{\int}_a^b (f+g)  - L(P,f)  <   \underline{\int}_a^b g,$$
and there exists a partition $P’$ such that
$$\underline{\int}_a^b (f+g)  - L(P,f)  <  L(P’,g) \leqslant \underline{\int}_a^b g.$$

Hence,
$$\underline{\int}_a^b (f+g)   <  L(P,f) + L(P’,g) .$$

Now take a common refinement of the partitions $Q = P \cup P'$.  Lower sums increase as partitions are refined and we have $L(Q,f) \geqslant L(P,f)$ and $L(Q,g) \geqslant L(P’,g).$

It follows that

$$\tag{2}L(Q,f+g) \leqslant \underline{\int}_a^b (f+g)   <  L(P,f) + L(P’,g)  \leqslant L(Q,f) + L(Q,g).$$

However, over any partition subinterval $I$ we have $\inf_{x \in I}f(x) + \inf_{x \in I}g(x) \leqslant \inf_{x \in I} (f+g)$ and it follows that

$$\tag{3}L(Q,f) + L(Q,g) \leqslant L(Q,f+g),$$

which contradicts (2).

Therefore,

$$\tag{4}\underline{\int}_a^b f + \underline{\int}_a^b g \leqslant \underline{\int}_a^b (f+g). $$

**Note**

A common mistake is to start with (3) and assume it implies (4) directly since

$$\sup_Q [L(Q,f) + L(Q,g)] \leqslant \sup_Q L(Q,f+g). $$

The problem is the only additional information that can be inferred directly from the definition of the supremum is

$$\sup_Q [L(Q,f) + L(Q,g)] \leqslant \sup_Q L(Q,f) + \sup_Q L(Q,g), $$

and we cannot determine the order relationship between the right-hand sides of the two inequalities.